# Python 'hhmmss' time calculation

Tags: python, datetime, time

I want to calculate 'hhmmss' format.

For example, '082358'(=08:23:58) plus 3 seconds so I can get '082401'.

```
Function(time, sec):  # Function('082358', 3)
     time += sec
     return time      # return '082401'
```

How can I

1. Invert string to time
2. Calculation
3. Invert time to string('hhmmss' format) again

Comment: Hi James,  Welcome to SO. I would like to say that StackOverflow questions should show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) and strftime, strptime from [datetime.datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def time_str_delta(time_str, sec):
    _time = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H%M%S')
    return (_time + timedelta(seconds=sec)).strftime('%H%M%S')
```